# RSpec / Webmock body response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using the webmock gem with rspec and I'm testing some functionality where I upload an image to a remote API. I want to stub the upload request to say that it will accept anything for the body. Is this possible?

e.g. something along the lines of

```
  it "uploads a photo" do
    image = "test_image.jpg"
    @meh.upload_image(image)
    stub_request(:post, "http://myurl").
         with(:body => *).
         to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
  end
```

Comment: `stub_request` should be called before making a request with `upload_image`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just ignore the `with(:body => *)` part.
If you want to ensure the body is not empty, you can use a regular expression i.e. `with(:body => /.+/)`

Comment: Cheers mate that was what I was after